Python requests returning Failed to resolve ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)
I downloaded the requests library and was following the quickstart example in their documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request, only to face the following error.
I tried replacing the URL with "https://www.google.com" and got the same error as well.
It's worth noting that I'm behind a proxy.
>>> import requests 
>>> >>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\User\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 203, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\User\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 954, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed


The issue arose  because I was behind a proxy.
To resolve this for a single request, simply add the proxies parameter.
import requests

proxies = {
  'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
  'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
}

requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)

Alternatively, configure the proxies for a session or set the required environment proxy environment variables.
More info on proxies from the documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies
