API Call working with Postman, failing with Python's request
If I test a postman post request I receive a status code 200 and receive a valid response as expected. When I try to use python's requests library I get the following error code:

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='myurl.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded
with url: /RestApi/v1/Authentication/RequestToken (Caused by
NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
0x000001A95F827220>: Failed to resolve 'myurl.com' ([Errno 11001]
getaddrinfo failed)"))

I tried my own implementation of the python request as well as the suggested code by postman:
import requests
import json

url = "https://myurl.com/RestApi/v1/Authentication/RequestToken"

payload = json.dumps({
    "Credentials": {
        "Username": "myUser",
        "Password": "myPassword"
    }
})
headers = {
    'Prefer': 'respond-async',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)

The requests are made from the same client (my laptop). Any idea why postman works while python fails?

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334199/getaddrinfo-failed-what-does-that-mean and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78291623/python-requests-returning-failed-to-resolve-errno-11001-getaddrinfo-failed particularly if you are behind a proxy server.
